# Django: Returning results into JSON from two mysql tables

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

Hello to the stackoverflow community,

I have the following two models defined as below (created by using python manage.py inspectdb) :

```
class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soccerseason = models.IntegerField(db_column='soccerSeason')  # Field name made lowercase.
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')
    fixturedate = models.DateTimeField()
    fixturestatus = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    fixturematchday = models.IntegerField()
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField()
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'

class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_team'
```

I then have a view as follows:

```
def jsonfixture(request):

    data = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(fixturematchday=12)


    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

This is working nicely and produces a usable result as follows:

```
[{"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": 70, "away_team": 328, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136932}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": 65, "away_team": 72, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136930}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 0, "home_team": 338, "away_team": 71, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 137852}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": 62, "away_team": 563, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136929}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 2, "home_team": 61, "away_team": 74, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136928}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 0, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": 67, "away_team": 69, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T15:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136931}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": 57, "away_team": 66, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-22T17:30:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136927}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 3, "home_team": 354, "away_team": 64, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-23T13:30:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136926}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 2, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": 322, "away_team": 73, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-23T16:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136925}, {"fields": {"awayteamscore": 1, "hometeamscore": 1, "home_team": 58, "away_team": 340, "fixturematchday": 12, "soccerseason": 354, "fixturedate": "2014-11-24T20:00:00", "fixturestatus": "FINISHED"}, "model": "straightred.straightredfixture", "pk": 136924}]
```

The only issue is that it is returning the "home_team" and "away_team" id and not the team name which is the desired outcome.

Previously I have used:

```
fixture = StraightredFixture.objects.get(fixtureid=136697)
return render(request,'straightred/test.html',{'name':fixture.away_team.teamname})
```

This works nicely and allows me to see the team name but I do not know how to pull the two concepts together into one.

After some research I thought I could simply use the ".select_related" option but it does not seem to change my output.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the `natural_key` method in your model, and set the flag when `serialize` the fixture, sample like this:

```
class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.teamname

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'straightred_team'
```

Then when serializing, just set the flag `use_natural_foreign_keys=True`:

```
json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

It should serialize the foreign key ids as their `teamname`.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys) you can read more about Django serializing and fixtures. You may also be interested in looking at [**dumpdata**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) management command.

Comment: The good news is that it worked perfectly.  The bad news is I don't know why... yet :)  I am off to read the link you sent to ensure I understand what is going on.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: @AlanTingey, lol no problem. Yes take a good look of the docs, it has explained quite in details on how to handle `serializing` and `deserializing` the fixtures. If you just want the fixtures, you may use `--dumpdata` instead, but if you need a custom solution where you can reuse the json output, then yes, you need a custom serializers